# How to add same code on multiple html pages for prev and next buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have more than 300 html pages, each page is named the same with 3 numbers at the end example
first page is named gs001.html, second gs002.html, third gs003.html etc... till gs330.html

I need code for previous and next buttons (preferably the code to be the same to paste on all pages)
For example if I'm on page gs150.html, need previous button to go to gs149.html and next button to go to gs151.html

Is this possible?

Comment: You really should use some kind of database for that. Maintinaing 300 HTML pages must be a *nightmare*.

Comment: You need to put the code in all 300 HTML pages. But the question is, what have you tried?

Comment: I can think of two or three ways you might do this without manually posting any code to any pages, but you've given no detail, so I can't tell which, if any, might be practical.

Comment: Well that's the first time I have ever heard of someone doing this.. What the hell is on each page? As someone said you should be using a database of some sort.

Comment: I agree that database is probably the best for this, but it started small with just a few pages, and it build over time, from the other side there are many refference links (from facebook) leading to my html pages which generate traffic and don't want to loose that. I tried this solution: [link](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/BackForwardNew.htm) but could not make it work.

Comment: You can still keep that traffic if you redirect all the html pages to a dynamic PHP (or whatever side script) page. Via htaccess or something like that. So suggest you start looking in to that for your own sake.

Comment: I'm not sure why everyone is jumping over databases and downvoting the question. Not every 300 (or 3000 for that matter) HTML page site needs database. It is perfectly legit question. This website may be legacy stuff out of OP's control or quick and dirty one off thing or could have been generated by tool or there is need to host it on very cheap servers or OP is just not comfortable using them. There are N number of reasons to avoid database as there are reasons to use databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do with just HTML and JavaScript:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function getNewUrl(addNum) {
            var url = window.location.pathname;
            var lastIndex = url.lastIndexOf('/');
            var filename = url.substring(lastIndex + 1);
            var newFileName = filename.substring(0, 2) +
                pad(parseInt(filename.substring(2, 5), 10) + addNum, 3) +
                filename.substring(5);
            return url.substring(0, lastIndex) + newFileName;
        }

        function pad(number, length) {
            var str = '' + number;
            while (str.length < length) {
                str = '0' + str;
            }
            return str;
        }

    </script>

    <button id="previous" onclick="window.location = getNewUrl(-1)">Previous</button>
    <button id="next" onclick="window.location = getNewUrl(1)">Next</button>


</body>
</html>
```

You can put the body of the code in your files and try it out.

Note that I've wrote above code in quick and dirty way. If you are going to production, you might want to use unobstructive JavaScript and put some error handling in place... It all depends on your application.

Comment: Thnx m8 very much. This works great if html files are in root directory. And when in subfolder newfilename is generated but it's just missing "/" before filename. How to make it work if the html files are in some subfolder?

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP if available on your server. Put a line of PHP at the top of each page that specifies the page number or let the PHP at the top work out the pagenumber from the filename.

Then include a standardised PHP file at the bottom of every page that works out the previous and next pages given the current pagenumber.

Comment: As I'm totaly inexperienced with PHP, can you please give me some sample code to play with, yes my server supports php

Comment: Have a quick look through the W3CSchools pages - they explain everything you need to know in about 15 minutes.http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp  Look here for include files http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp    And look here for variables http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp